# HTML >> Multiple languages in the same <select> menu

Tags: character, html-select

Need to create a `<select>` element where each of the options is written in a different language.

I've tried using the "lng" tag for the `<option>` but it's not helping.

The drop-down is generated from a call to the DB. Each `<option>` needs to have the following format: 
Language Name (in English) followed by the original language name in parentheses.

For example:

```
<option>Spanish (Español)</option>
```

Everything is fine and dandy until I get to foreign character sets, which don't display:

```
<option>Akan (Twi)</option>

<option>Amharic (????)</option>

<option>Arabic (????????????)</option>

<option>Bengali (?????)</option>

<option>Chinese (????)</option>
```

Does anyone know how to create a drop-down containing multiple character sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the parameters of the DB connection string. I added ";charset=utf8".

However, that scrambled many of my other pages so I now have a separate DB connection string just for the page that I need this multi-language drop down on.

You can see the results here http://udhr.video.

Comment: Those problems are not easy to debug without direct acess to your code and already stored data. You probably already stored your data using the wrong encoding in your connection. The encoding set for your connection should alway reflect the encoding of the data you send or the one you want to display.